# Adding GeoJSON layer to a Layergroup so that it shows as radio button in layer control?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, layer-control

I want to display both the basemaps and the overlaymaps with radio buttons in my LayerControl. I tried this via Layergroups and ran into some difficulties there.

I have two GeoJSON layers that get their data from a $ajax query.

I want only one GeoJSON layer to be active at a time. Since I am a beginner in this field I lack a lot of knowledge and understanding.

Currently I am trying to modify an example from the internet so that I can use it for my file.

This is the .js file I want to implement the GeoJSON:

```
(function() {

  var basemaps = {
  
    Streets: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }),
    googleSat:  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      maxZoom: 20,
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
      attribution: "<a href=\'http://maps.google.com/\'>Google</a> Maps Satellite",
      noWrap: true
    })
  };


  

  var groups = {
    cities: new L.LayerGroup(),
    restaurants: new L.LayerGroup(),
    dogs: new L.LayerGroup(),
    cats: new L.LayerGroup()
  };


  window.ExampleData = {
    LayerGroups: groups,
    Basemaps: basemaps

  };

}());
```

This is the GeoJson:

```
 var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
                

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://',
                data: {
                    version: '1.0.0',
                    request: 'GetFeature',
                    service: 'WFS',
                    typeName: '',
                    maxFeatures: '2000',
                    outputFormat: 'application/json'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: handleJson
             });
             //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             
        
        
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////Funktion handleJson 
            function handleJson(data) {
               
                //Daten aus Ajaxabfrage dem Leaflet GeoJSON Layer zuweisen
                geojsonLayer.addData(data);

                /////Stringkonvertierung der Einzelobjekt Properties der einzelnen Länder
                jproperties = JSON.stringify(data.features.map(function (el) { return el.properties; }));
                ////Parsen der Zeichenkette des JSON in JavaScript Objekt
                js_objects_of_json_string = JSON.parse(jproperties);
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                
        
                ///Anzahl der Einzelobjekte bzw. Länder ermitteln
                obj_count = js_objects_of_json_string.length;           
                
                
                /////For-Schleife mit der hier Impfzahl (scases) und Bevölkerungszahl (mpop) ausgelesen werden
                for (var i = 0; i < obj_count; i++) {
                    
                    if (js_objects_of_json_string[i]['population']>0) {
                    vaccinated_per_pop = (js_objects_of_json_string[i]['mpeople_vaccinated']/js_objects_of_json_string[i]['population']);  ///hier mit Auslesen Berechnung für Impfrate prozentual zur Gesamtbevölkerung
                    } 
            
                    /////Arrays mit den Objektdaten füllen und dabei Impfrate in %///////////////////////////
                    vaccinated_per_object_arr.push(js_objects_of_json_string[i]['mpeople_vaccinated']);
                    all_vaccinated_per_pop_arr.push(vaccinated_per_pop*100);
                }////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

             
              
                /////Maximalwerte der Fälle und der Verhälniszahl Fälle pro 100.000 EW ermitteln, wichtig für Berechnungen zur Rangedefinition für Farbgebung und Legende
                max_mpeople_vaccinated = Math.max.apply(null, vaccinated_per_object_arr);
                max_mpeople_vaccinated_per_pop = Math.max.apply(null, all_vaccinated_per_pop_arr);
        
                //Maximalzahl der Fälle auf Ganzzahl gerundet
                max_mpeople_vaccinated_per_pop = Math.round(max_mpeople_vaccinated_per_pop); 
                // Hier prozentualer Maximalwert der Impfrate als Maximalwertdefinition für die Farbklassen 
                max_vaccinated_per_pop_allowed = max_mpeople_vaccinated_per_pop;
                console.log(max_mpeople_vaccinated_per_pop);
        
        
                ///Methodenaufruf Styledefinition des GeoJSON Layers
                geojsonLayer.setStyle(style);
                
                ///Methodenaufruf zur Generierung der Legende für das L-Mapobjekt
                legend.addTo(map);
                
            }/////Ende der Funktion handleJson//////////////////////////////////////////////

        
 
        
        ///Funktion zur Gestaltung der Choropletenkarte///////////////////
            function style(feature) {
                
                //Ausgabe des Inhalts von data in der Konsole
                //console.log(feature);
            
                //Berechnung des Verhältnissses der Impfungen zur Einwohnerzahl eines Landes
                vaccinated_per_pop = (feature.properties.mpeople_vaccinated/feature.properties.population);
        
                return {
                ////Generierung der Polygonfärbung eines Objektes über Funktion mit Chroma.js unter Berücksichtung des Maximalwerts der damit maximale Klassenobergrenze definiert
                   fillColor: colorRamp(vaccinated_per_pop*100/max_vaccinated_per_pop_allowed),  
            
                    weight: 0.5,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'black',
                    dashArray: '1',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7 
                } 
            }/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            
        
            
            var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature});


            map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want for overlays `cities`, `restaurants`, `dogs` and `cats` only one to be selected simultaneously. When another one is selected, the currect one should be deselected. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet control `L.control.layers` has no option/possibility to have radio buttons for overlays, but you can listen to map's `overlayadd` and `overlayremove` events and hide currently selected overlay when some other overlay is selected.

For this you set up some global variable `selectedOverlay` where currently selected overlay will be stored. When `overlayadd` event is fired, you remove currently selected overlay stored in `selectedOverlay` variable and store in it newly selected one. This has to be done outside event processing function, so `setTimeout` with slight delay is used for that.

Some generic code for that could look something like this:

```
var baseLayers = {"OSM": osmLayer};

var overlayLayers = {
  "Overlay 1": geoJsonLayer1,
  "Overlay 2": geoJsonLayer2
};

var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [52, -1],
  zoom: 8,
  zoomControl: false, 
  layers: [local]
});

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayLayers, {position: 'topright', collapsed: false }).addTo(map);

var selectedOverlay = null;

function updateSelectedOverlay(layer) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (selectedOverlay) map.removeLayer(selectedOverlay);
    selectedOverlay = layer;
  }, 10);
}

map.on('overlayadd', function(event) {
  updateSelectedOverlay(event.layer)
});
map.on('overlayremove', function(event) {
  selectedOverlay = null;
});
```

If you want one of the overlays initially to be selected, like `layers: [local, geoJsonLayer1]`, then `selectedOverlay` has to be initialized to that overlay: `var selectedOverlay = geoJsonLayer1`.